# How do I dynamically name a collection?

Tags: syntax, neo4j, cypher

Title: How do I dynamically name a collection?

Pseudo-code: `collect(n) AS :Label`

The primary purpose of this is for easy reading of the properties in the API Server (node application).

**Verbose example:**

```
MATCH (user:User)--(n)
WHERE n:Movie OR n:Actor
RETURN user,
CASE
    WHEN n:Movie THEN "movies"
    WHEN n:Actor THEN "actors"
END as type, collect(n) as :type
```

**Expected output in JSON:**

```
[{
    "user": {
        ....
    },


    "movies": [
        {
            "_id": 1987,
            "labels": [
                "Movie"
            ],
            "properties": {
                ....
            }
        }
    ],

    "actors:" [ .... ]
}]
```

*The closest I've gotten is:*

```
[{
    "user": {
        ....
    },

    "type": "movies",
    "collect(n)": [
        {
            "_id": 1987,
            "labels": [
                "Movie"
            ],
            "properties": {
                ....
            }
        }
    ]
}]
```

The goal is to be able to read the JSON result with ease like so:

```
neo4j.cypher.query(statement, function(err, results) {
    for result of results
    var user = result.user
    var movies = result.movies
}
```

**Edit:**
I apologize for any confusion in my inability to correctly name database semantics.

Comment: Can you add in your expectation of the output when there are both related movies and actors? You are going to get both at once in the same row...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Whenever I tried this on a working data set, collect(n) managed to get both sets into two different arrays, which is why I need to dynamically name that array set, rather than as collect(n) in the returned data.

What I'm looking for is a way to do var movies = response.movies, etc.

Comment: I've updated the example to hopefully clarify the expected output.

Comment: Thanks. And yes you're correct (and I was mistaken), the existence of the type output divides up movies and actors into different rows nicely, though this doesn't seem like what you want it to do...

Comment: Two different rows is acceptable, as long as I can sort them by property names in nodejs. Currently, the array name is just `collect(n)`

Comment: Just to note, the title of this question isn't really accurate, as the actual need and the selected answer had nothing to do with dynamically named collections; the types of nodes collected and the column names were done explicitly, not dynamically.

Comment: I apologize that the naming conventions weren't accurate. I'm not a database person so I wasn't sure of the correct naming. I just wanted to have collections of nodes connected to the :User that were named based on associated labels, in this example :Actor and :Movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm wondering if it's enough just to output the user and their lists of both actors and movies, rather than trying to do a more complicated means of matching and combining both.

```
MATCH (user:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)--(m:Movie)
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)--(a:Actor)
RETURN user, COLLECT(m) as movies, COLLECT(a) as actors
```

Comment: This request, as written, will fail to return anything unless a user is related to both movies and actors.

Comment: @cybersam Thanks for catching that! Updated to use optional matches.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: I agree that this is the best answer. But I should mention that my answer (although more complex), should return the same collections.

Comment: Whenever I tried your answer, the movies were nested behind the actors which is undesirable for what I want. I only used the movies/actors example as it's the easiest to provide examples. I was looking for a solution that provides all connections to the user, while providing a list of potential labels, then sorting each into their own array/set.

Comment: @LeviRoberts Given that comment, I can't say that my answer does that at all. It works in the explicit case you gave in your description, but not the dynamic case you seem to need.

Comment: You are correct. However it will work for my needs. I can just add additional labels (cypher lines) in the language as needed. If there was a way to do it dynamically, that would obviously be superior.. but alas, I'll settle.

Comment: It appears that I spoke too soon. The OPTIONAL MATCH (:a:Actor) does not produce the expected result. It appears to just duplicate nodes, perhaps from the previous match. Could it also be that the optional :Actor is finding a path through the :Movie nodes?

Comment: It appears by removing the Collect(a) fixes the issue but I'm unsure of what the repercussions are. Also changing the syntax to COLLECT(DISTINCT a) works. Again, not sure what this entails. Without this appears to duplicate them for as many previous :m nodes there are.

Comment: It won't find paths through the :Movie nodes, that's not in your match criteria (the -- indicates a single relationship, though it can be a relationship of any kind). The reason multiple matches are showing up is due to multiple relationships to actors (or movies). For example, if a user directed and produced a movie, movie would occur twice. If a user knows and likes an actor, they would occur twice. Adding DISTINCT within your collect ensures you will only get one occurrence of the thing in your collection.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It's very much appreciated. There's a lot of new information to take in when using a new database and not all edge cases are covered in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

This query should return each `User` and his/her related movies and actors (in separate collections):

```
MATCH (user:User)--(n)
WHERE n:Movie OR n:Actor
RETURN user,
  REDUCE(s = {movies:[], actors:[]}, x IN COLLECT(n) |
    CASE WHEN x:Movie
      THEN {movies: s.movies + x, actors: s.actors}
      ELSE {movies: s.movies, actors: s.actors + x}
    END) AS types;
```

Comment: Thank you for providing your answer. Although it's not what I'm looking for. I basically just want to sort the collect sets by a dynamic property name (the label)

Comment: You want to sort by the label? Can you clarify what that means?

Answer (score 1):

As far as a dynamic solution to your question, one that will work with any node connected to your user, there are a few options, but I don't believe you can get the column names to be dynamic like this, or even the names of the collections returned, though we can associate them with the type.

```
MATCH (user:User)--(n)
WITH user, LABELS(n) as type, COLLECT(n) as nodes
WITH user, {type:type, nodes:nodes} as connectedNodes
RETURN user, COLLECT(connectedNodes) as connectedNodes
```

Or, if you prefer working with multiple rows, one row each per node type:

```
MATCH (user:User)--(n)
WITH user, LABELS(n) as type, COLLECT(n) as collection
RETURN user, {type:type, data:collection} as connectedNodes
```

Note that `LABELS(n)` returns a list of labels, since nodes can be multi-labeled. If you are guaranteed that every interested node has exactly one label, then you can use the first element of the list rather than the list itself. Just use `LABELS(n)[0]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically sort nodes by label, and then convert to the map using the [`apoc library`](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures#map-functions):

```
WITH ['Actor','Movie'] as LBS
// What are the nodes we need:
MATCH (U:User)--(N) WHERE size(filter(l in labels(N) WHERE l in LBS))>0
WITH U, LBS, N, labels(N) as nls
UNWIND nls as nl
  // Combine the nodes on their labels:
  WITH U, LBS, N, nl WHERE nl in LBS
  WITH U, nl, collect(N) as RELS
  WITH U, collect( [nl, RELS] ) as pairs
  // Convert pairs "label - values" to the map:
  CALL apoc.map.fromPairs(pairs) YIELD value
RETURN U as user, value
```